# What is the chatLengthEstimator.cmsketch file located in the Library/Suggestions folder? (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos

I stumbled upon the Suggestions folder `/Users/zezuz/Library/Suggestions`  while browsing through my MacBook Pro, running High Sierra. (which btw, I never knew even existed)

In the folder is a file named `chatLengthEstimator.cmsketch`. I tried to view it but no program I have can open a .cmsketch file. Clicking the "search App Store" option resulted in nothing.

A google search also returned little, but it seems that it's some sort of sample or database file, possibly related to TIDB?

My questions are:

1. What is a .cmsketch file?
2. What is, specifically, the chatLengthEstimator.cmsketch file and why is it being "suggested" to me?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to open any file that you have no information about.

1. Copy it to the desktop (copy not move so you don't damage the original)
2. Rename the file by placing a ".txt" at the end
3. MacOS will ask you to confirm that you really want to change the extension
4. Once changed double click on what macOS now thinks is a text file and it will open in TextEdit.app

If it is a binary file you will see just seemingly random unreadable characters and the occasional readable word. Which means it is a file that macOS or an application uses for whatever purpose and is only readable by macOS or the Application.

If it is filled with readable text it may be a human readable configuration file or a dictionary of some sort.

If you have a third-party text editor (BBedit springs to mind) it will open any file without changing the extension. Just drag the file to the application icon.

Once you have opened the file you may be able to tell by the contents what the file does. Often random human readable strings in a binary file can hint at what the file's purpose is.

Failing that signing up for an Apple Developer account might give you access to information about macOS internals and that particular file.

Answer (score 1):

The files in `~/Library/Suggestions` are used internally to support some of macOS's machine learning features, like Spotlight Suggestions, Suggested Contacts, and data detectors. These files are not being suggested *to you*.

A `.cmSketch` file probably contains a [count-min sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch) data structure. It does not contain any human-readable data. Given the name of this file, it is probably used to estimate how often, or for how long, you chat with your contacts on iMessage.